# create a sequence in oracle for each block

Tags: oracle, block, sequence

I learnt how to create a simple sequence by :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE wrk_fil_cde_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

this will create a sequence which increment by 1 for each row...but I need something different. I need for each row from Deb1 till Deb2 seq_col should be 1, after appear of Deb2 it should be increased by 1, like :

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear what do you want. For each row from Deb1 till Deb2 seq_col should be 1, after appear of Deb2 it shoul be increased by 1? Is that what you want?

Comment: I would suggest you do this when outputting the values, rather than when inserting values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Or generating the value as part of the load depending on the precise use case.

Comment: @JustinCave please how can I do this

Comment: How is the data being loaded into this table?  Since a heap-organized table is inherently unordered, how do you know which rows are between "Deb1" and "FIN1"?  What column are you ordering by to cause the results to be ordered the way you present?  Is there a third unpictured column that gives the order?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a trigger.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
p_seq_id number;
BEGIN
SELECT nvl(max(seq_col) ,0)
INTO p_seq_id 
FROM your_table;

IF :NEW.val_col LIKE 'Deb%' THEN
:NEW.seq_col = p_seq_id + 1;
ELSE 
:NEW.seq_col = p_seq_id;
END IF;

END;
```

But it will not work for updates. Because it is not really clear how to determine, that row is between Deb1 and Deb2...

If you really want to use sequence it could be done like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

IF :NEW.val_col LIKE 'Deb%' THEN
:NEW.seq_col = wrk_fil_cde_seq.nextval;
ELSE 
:NEW.seq_col = wrk_fil_cde_seq.currval;
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: First thanks for you answer. There are any other suggestions without trigger

Comment: @Abderrahim how do you want to fill this field using sequence? In insert statement or automatically?

Comment: Yes I prefer sequence :)

Comment: sequence is a separate object in database. It is not related to table till you create trigger which insert value in table using sequence. So you always need a trigger to fill field automatically. That's why your question  **without trigger** a not understandable for me

Comment: Because I am using Oracle Data intergrator and the table don't exist in the first instance , the ODI will create automatically when I run my mapping you know the trigger need the table exist already in my database for that I need something else as a solution

Comment: With sequence you can use currval value - it returns not next value, but current. `wrk_fil_cde_seq.currval` Maybe that will helps. Nothing else I can suggest

Comment: but the trigger always here anyway your answers are very useful thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92753/discussion-between-abderrahim-and-tatiana).